# Wash or Wash up

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense

Today i used to tell my friend on a chatsite:

> Finally you **washed** your greasy hair.

Suddenly another person appeared there and corrected me that it should be **Washed up**.

My sentence is wrong? and if i have to use Washed up in my sentence, Tell me why would i use it (reasons)?

Comment: Flagged to move this to ELL.

Comment: Whoever told you that is washed up.

Comment: I've washed **down** many a dirty wall myself. The direction is optional and variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *British* English, you wash your face or your hair, and 'washing up' refers to washing dishes.

Comment: So the person who told me that its Washed up was a meathead?

Comment: In American English, you wouldn't say *I washed up my hair*. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wash%20up) says  *wash up* means *"to wash one's face and hands"*. I would say it means to generally make oneself cleaner without actually taking a bath or shower, which is more or less the same idea.

Comment: I was about to reply, saying I *thought* Americans use 'washing up' for personal washing, but Peter Shore got there and confirmed it.

Comment: Actually its annoying as soon as i encounter the words such as Wash up, Wash down, Rub off , Rub down, ... Doesnt it have an acceptable grammar to know how to use them?

Comment: I'll leave that to an expert, and just say that all these hundreds of phrases are one of things that make learning English so hard, while native speakers claim that their language 'hardly has any grammar.'

Comment: Basically, "wash up" is treated idiomatically as if it were intransitive.  You don't "wash up something", you just "wash up".  There is generally an implicit object of the verb, which might be a sinkfull of dishes or might be your face and hands (eg, before eating), or might be your entire body.  But it's implied (or somehow specified elsewhere in the sentence).